# jQuery - Prepend an image to parent div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-hover

Goal is to have an animation appear on mouseover and disappear on mouseout. Using jQuery within WordPress, hence the no-conflict tags.

What works? FadeTo on hover and adding/removing the additional class. This is happening on a per-item basis.

What doesn't? I've got the new image prepending accurately on hover, but hovering over any img.readmore is firing on all the .entry-content divs. I've tried traversing the DOM to find parent (which I couldn't quite get working) & I've tried using `$( $img ).prependTo( $(this) );` which failed too.

I'd appreciate help in 
a) targeting only the div that is hovered over (primary need), and
b) advice on tidying things up for a new JS person.

```
    /*
    * Readmore animation
     */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //add readmore class to images (temp, will eventually live in markup)
    $(".post-image").addClass("readmore");

    //fade original image on hover
    $("img.readmore").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass("readmore-hover").fadeTo( "slow" , 0.1 );
    }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("readmore-hover").fadeTo( "fast" , 1 );
    }
);

//prepend new image on hover

    //what's our img?
    var $img = $("<img src='/path/to/readmore_hover.png' style='position: absolute; left: 15%;opacity:0.7 !important' />");

    //prepend new image on hover
    $("img.readmore").hover(
        function() {
            $( $img ).prependTo( ".entry-content" );
        }),
     function () {
    //      remove img on mouseout;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific bug, or are you looking for more efficient, or otherwise "better" solutions? Could you make a jsfiddle? Edit: Saw what you'd appreciate help in, and a jsfiddle would still be helpful to see the layout of your html and to iterate on publicly.

Comment: Will get onto a jsfiddle with some mark-up now. Specific point of failure right now is that the prependTo needs to preppend only to the .entry-content element that's being hovered on, rather than every .entry-content element on the page.

Comment: can you provide the html so I can figure out a selector for the target entry-content?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8x5g5/

Comment: So the actual thing you want to do is to replace the placeholder with the 'more' image when hover?

Comment: No, the more image should be superimposed over the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the image to **prependTo** the appropriate **div**.

```
$( $img ).prependTo( $(this).closest(".entry-content") );
```

I'm still working on the **remove()** function.

### EDIT

I really like Leglaws **id** selector to remove the image so here it is complete!

```
<html>

<script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //add readmore class to images (temp, will eventually live in markup)
    $(".post-image").addClass("readmore");

    //fade original image on hover
    $("img.readmore").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).stop();
            $(this).addClass("readmore-hover").fadeTo( "slow" , 0.1 );
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop();
            $(this).removeClass("readmore-hover").fadeTo( "fast" , 1 );
        }
    );

//prepend new image on hover

    //what's our img?
    var $img = $("<img id='inserted' src='/path/to/readmore_hover.png'" + 
        "style='position: absolute; left: 15%;opacity:0.7 !important' />");

    //prepend new image on hover
    $("img.readmore").hover(
        function() {
            $( $img ).prependTo( $(this).closest(".entry-content") );
        },
        function () {
            //      remove img on mouseout;
            $('#inserted').remove();
        })

});
</script>

<body>
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="http://google.com"><img class="readmore"
        style="z-index:2;" src="some_image.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="http://yahoo.com"><img class="readmore"
        style="z-index:2;" src="some_image.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img class="readmore"
        style="z-index:2;" src="some_image.png" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add your own images to this.

There was also an error in the **//prepend new image on hover** functions.  The closing brace **}** on the first function had the closing parentheses **)** immediately following it.  It should have been at the end of the second function (removing the image).

The **flickering** as you called it is actually the result of not telling the animation you started with the **fadeTo()** functions to stop when you have removed the mouse hover.  So what's happening is that you are queueing up the animations each time you hover over it.  It's easy to check this by just running your mouse over the image several times and let go of the mouse.  You'll actually see it go through each of the animations you placed into the queue.  **stop()** is just one of jQuery's animation extras.

For the original images that appear and fade away, you want to set the style to **z-index=2;**.  This keeps the faded out image in front of the new img so you can still do the click-through you mentioned in your comments below.

Now I really believe that this is complete.  haha

Awesome!

c0p

Comment: This successfully traverses up the DOM to target the correct element. Success. Thanks.

Comment: Great. This does just what I was after. 

It's introduced two new issues for one: one is a flicker on the fade/load image which I'm working on; the second is the inability to click through, because the new image sits between the user's pointer and the link on the image below.

Comment: Is that a new question?  haha  Those issues can be fixed also.

Comment: Alright, here you go.  Community site, right? Add **$(this).stop();** before the **addClass** and **removeClass** functions.  Then add **z-index:2;** to the style of each of the original images.  Also see the **REVISED** final code above.

Comment: You're a legend! I set aside time to work on that this weekend, but you've saved me that. Once I get some reputation points I'm coming back to send some your way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The error happens on this `$( $img ).prependTo( ".entry-content" );`. The selector `.entry-content` will select all the entries. You should specify the target entry you want. `$this` is currently the `readmore` item you are hovering. So you have to figure out a selector to identify the target entry item.

http://jsfiddle.net/93TCZ/

Comment: Exactly. That's what I described (or tried to) in my original question. The issue at stake here is how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the inserted image so its easy to reference on removal. Then prepend the image in some fashion like:

```
$("img.readmore").hover(
  function() {
    $( $img ).prependTo($(this));
  },
  function () {
    $("img#inserted").remove();
  }
);
```